# Regex to match file name with or without extension

Tags: regex, nginx

How do I modify `^(.*/)index\.html$` properly to match index.html **with or without extension** ?

```
example.com/index.html - match        
example.com/index - match
example.com/indexx - ignore

if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.html$") {
    return 301 $1;
}
```

Comment: `^(.*/)index(\.html)?$`

Comment: Thanks, can you post it as an answer, so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping `\.html` into a capture group and making it optional `?` (match zero or one time) allows you to make the extension optional:

```
# your regex:
^(.*/)index\.html$

# change to:
^(.*/)index(\.html)?$
#          ^      ^^
```

Comment: Building on that, you don't need the first match (nor the second) so you could simplify as: `/index(?:\.html)?`.